# Is there any document of Apache Flink runtime contexts?

Tags: apache-flink

I know flink has some predefined variables such as `<host>`, I can get it via:
context.getMetricGroup().getAllVariables().get("`<host>`")

Is there any detailed document about all those variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all information about metrics (and also samples of using them) used in Apache Flink in the documentation here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/monitoring/metrics.html

Comment: Found it. Thanks a lot!